# Bash Script with smartctl not working

Tags: linux, bash, cron, nas

I am pretty new to bash scripting, but I upon setting up a NAS with FreeNAS I found that the GUI has no default implementation for logging HDD temperatures, so I tried to set up a bash script that would log temps to a file and run as a cron job. What I ended up piecing together looks very messy, but works when run as a script from the console.

HDDtemps.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash --
PATH=$PATH:/tmp:/usr/local/sbin
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' $(echo -n $(date +"%b %d %T")) ' :: ada0 Temperature Celsius =   ' $(echo $(smartctl -A /dev/ada0 | grep Temperature_Celsius) | awk '{print $10}') >> temperatures.txt
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' $(echo -n $(date +"%b %d %T")) ' :: ada1 Temperature Celsius =   ' $(echo $(smartctl -A /dev/ada1 | grep Temperature_Celsius) | awk '{print $10}') >> temperatures.txt
exit;
```

When executed by cron however, the file is created and is printed into, but only

`Feb 17 19:22:00  :: ada0 Temperature Celsius =`

is written to the file, the temperature is does not appear. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The cronjob is

`* * * * * sh /path/to/HDDtemps.sh`

Comment: Have you installed smartmontools [smartmontools](http://www.smartmontools.org/)

Comment: Yes, like I said the script runs as expected when executed through the console, the temperatures are written properly to the file, it is only an issue from the cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, verify that the **smartctl** binary is present in **/usr/sbin/** and specify the absolute path **/usr/sbin/smartctl** for **smartctl** in the script runned by cronjob, so replace **smartctl** with **/usr/sbin/smartctl**.